# Get dynamic count of visible elements by class name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the linked fiddle, I have set up a checkbox filter in jQuery to filter people by company name and job title. I would like to have a total count of visible elements that dynamically changes when elements are shown/hidden. In the fiddle, I have the total element count highlighted, but it currently does not change when checkboxes are checked/unchecked. I have found several questions that are similar, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to implement those suggestions into my code to make the count dynamic. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/point71echo/fnzag0pp/6/

Here's the jQuery code I am using:

```
    $(function() {
        $('.peoples, .companies').on('click', function() {
            var checkedPeoples = $('.peoples:checked');
            var checkedCompanies = $('.companies:checked');
            if (checkedPeoples.length || checkedCompanies.length) {
                if (checkedCompanies.length === 0) {
                    $('.row > div').hide();
                    $.each(checkedPeoples, function() {
                        var prdId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                        $('.row > div[data-category="' + prdId + '"]').show();
                    });
                } else if (checkedPeoples.length === 0) {
                    $('.row > div').hide();
                    $.each(checkedCompanies, function() {
                        var brandId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                        $('.row > div[company="' + brandId + '"]').show();
                    });
                } else {
                    $('.row > div').hide();
                    $.each(checkedPeoples, function() {
                        var prdId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                        $.each(checkedCompanies, function() {
                            var brandId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                            $('.row > div[data-category="' + prdId + '"][company="' + brandId + '"]').show();
                        });
                    });
                }
            } else {
                $('.row > div').show();
            }
        });
    });

// Total count of elements (visible and invisible)...
var x = $('.people:visible').length;
$('#count').append( x );
```

Comment: You have 2 classes for "people" one has an "s" on the end... I presume this is a typo? (An on a nit picky note "people" is plural already, there's no need for an "s" ;-)

Comment: As for the dynamic issue, a simple change event handler on your checkboxes (and/or whatever shows/hides them) could do the quick re-calc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as easy as counting the visible elements and changing the HTML at the bottom of your event handler

```
$('#count').html( $('.people:visible').length );
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/fnzag0pp/7/)

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you for providing this quick and simple solution.